# Replace html text with span using jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

I want to change text content of HTML elements with a span with some background color. 
The HTML is in form like this

```
  <html>
   <head></head>
   <body>Gc <br>
   Stable <br>
   Oral intake better <br>
   Urine stool normal <br>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have keywords like below which need to be matched :

```
Gc,Stable,Oral,Urine
```

I have html in form of string

```
"<html><head></head><body>Gc <br>Stable <br>Oral intake better <br>Urine stool normal <br>Pain Relief <br>Vital stable <br>No problem <br>Adv tab pan 40mg 1od <br>Tab pcm500mg 6hourly <br>Cab gab 300mg 1bd <br>Cab becasol 1od <br>Cab Tramadol 50mg 6hourly   </body></html>"
```

I want to match element text content and replace them with the keywords if it matches in HTML string. I would change them with span having given background color and text of match keywords.

Resultant HTML would be like below.

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>   
   <div>
     <span style="background: #FF9999;">Gc</span> 
    <br><span style="background: #FF9999;">Stable</span> 
    <br><span style="background: #FF9999;">Oral</span> intake better 
    <br><span style="background: #FF9999;">Urine</span> stool normal 
    <br>Pain Relief 
    <br>Vital stable 
    <br>No problem 
    <br>Adv tab pan 40mg 1od 
    <br>Tab pcm500mg 6hourly 
    <br>Cab gab 300mg 1bd 
    <br>Cab becasol 1od 
    <br>Cab Tramadol 50mg 6hourly 
   </div>  
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve it in java. I am using jsoup library.

This code is working for me. Is this the optimum approach?. Or any better way for replacing html string

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.parser.Tag;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class regexReplaceHtml {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        String html2 = "<html><head></head><body>Gc <br>Stable <br>Oral intake better <br>Urine stool normal <br>Pain Relief <br>Vital stable <br>No problem <br>Adv tab pan 40mg 1od <br>Tab pcm500mg 6hourly <br>Cab gab 300mg 1bd <br>Cab becasol 1od <br>Cab Tramadol 50mg 6hourly   </body></html>";


        String html = "<div>" + html2 + "</div>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
        keywords.add("Gc");
        keywords.add("Stable");
        keywords.add("Oral");
        keywords.add("Urine");

        String convertedString = replaceHtmlString(doc.html(),keywords);

        System.out.println(convertedString);

    }

   public static String replaceHtmlString(String html, List<String> keywords) {
        String htmlString = "<div>" + html + "</div>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
        Elements elements = doc.body().children().select("*");

        for (Element element : elements) {

            List<TextNode> tnList = element.textNodes();

            for (TextNode tn : tnList) {
                String nodeTrimmedText = tn.text().trim();

                for (int i = 0; i < keywords.size(); i++) {
                    String keyword = keywords.get(i);
                    if (isContainExactWord(nodeTrimmedText, keyword)) {
                        String nodeText = tn.text();
                        String keywordHtmlString = "<span style=\"background: #FF9999;\">" + keyword + "</span>";
                        String replacedTextHtmlString = nodeText.replace(keyword, keywordHtmlString);
                        tn.text(replacedTextHtmlString);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        //I had to replace the &lt; and &gt; with the respective symbols
        return doc.html().replaceAll("&lt;", "<").replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
    }

    private static boolean isContainExactWord(String fullString, String partWord) {
        String pattern = "\\b" + partWord + "\\b";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(fullString);
        return m.find();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you have your html as string the simples solution is to use String.replace() method.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want. It takes a list of keywords and replaces them with the span tag you mentioned.

```
List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
keywords.add("Gc");
keywords.add("Stable");
keywords.add("Oral");
keywords.add("Urine");

Element body = doc.getElementsByTag("body").first();

List<TextNode> nodes = body.textNodes();

for(TextNode node : nodes){
    String nodeText = node.text();

    for(String keyword : keywords){
        if(nodeText.contains(keyword)){
            String newText = nodeText.replace(keyword, "");
            node.text(newText);

            node.before("<span style=\"background-color:#FF9999;\">" + keyword + "</span>");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is regexp solution:

```
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(Gc|Stable|Oral|Urine)").matcher(html);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                html = html.replace(matcher.group(i), String.format("<span style=\"background-color:#FF9999;\">%s</span>", matcher.group(i)));
            }
        }
```